# Expectation Maximization in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, expectation-maximization

In the Internet, there are many code examples for C ++ or Python. But there is not a single example in C #.

I tried it myself and got an error.

```
 EM em = EM.Create();
 em.ClustersNumber = 2;
 em.CovarianceMatrixType = (int) EM.Types.CovMatGeneric; // <=System.AccessViolationException
 em.TermCriteria = new TermCriteria(type: CriteriaType.MaxIter, maxCount: 1500, epsilon: 0.001);
```

What is my problem? Can someone help with a working example on the topic of Expectation Maximization?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Expectation-Maximization_in_CSharp) help?

Comment: This page was last modified on 24 November 2010, at 06:06.

Comment: Try to find for OpenCVSharp (by Shimat). You will not find.